# What is advantage/disadvantage of creating soft link to executable file in /bin?

Tags: linux, terminal

I often use this way to make my executable appear in terminal. Is it good or bad? And why?

Comment: What is "your executable"? A program of your own? Do you share the system with other users?

Comment: I mean file that can be execute, may be downloaded program or anything else. And I don't share my system with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with leaving a symlink to an executable in `/bin`. In fact, it could be a very clean way of managing your executables, compared to putting every single executable's path in your `$PATH`.

So, instead of having, for example, `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` in your `$PATH`, you'd have `/home/user/foo/bin:/home/user/bar/bin:/yet/another/bin:/usr/local/bin`, etc. which would be hard to maintain. Plus, you'd have to set up your custom path for all shells, whereas simply putting the symlink into `/bin` makes it available to any shell right away.

But this is your choice. Often, programs will have to have a `FOO_HOME` variable set, pointing to their directory, e.g. `TOMCAT_HOME`, which contains a `bin` directory of its own.

---

Maybe you should consider using `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`, because the latter is usually reserved for essential system binaries that are available to all users, and `/usr/bin` is for non-essential binaries.

Even better would be to use `/usr/local/bin`, since `/usr/local` is the default place for anything you've installed yourself, as a user—so anything that is not part of a default system installation. If `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH`, you should of course add it.

To find out more about the directory organization, read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html).

Comment: +1 for /usr/local/bin.  The /bin and /usr/bin directories should be maintained by the package manager, /usr/local/bin should be used for programs installed manually, and useful shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin` is used for executables used by the kernel. `/usr/bin/` Is I think  for your distibutions package manager. You can freely add links to your executables to `/usr/local/bin` which is typically where software that you compile would install themselves with a `make install`

The ideal method is to add `~/bin` to your path, create that folder in your home directory and just use that folder.

Of course all this is mostly about neatness, elegance, correctness, etc. I cant think of a reasonable technical flaw in linking directly to `/bin` as long as you do it correctly with no mistakes ever.